# Choosing top rankings from data frame columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   a  b    c    d    e
1 47Z TS2  TS2  3SU  3SU
2 TS2 47Z  3SU  K5S  47Z
3 3SU A2D  A2D  47Z  A2D
4 FZT 3SU  FZT  FZT  RF9
5 A2D K5S       TS2
```

Each column represents a ranking for one feature (a-d here). The codes used in the rankings must not appear in every column (but they can) and the rankings do not have the same length. In the original file there are about 60 rankings/columns with 10-20 codes each.

So I now want to select the first x codes in the rankings (with x = 2 in this example), wich have not been chosen more than twice before. For the example above this would be the result:

```
   a  b    c    d    e
1 47Z TS2  3SU  3SU  A2D
2 TS2 47Z  A2D  K5S  RF9
```

The order of the appearance is not important.

I have to admit that I have no idea how to implement that without using several for-loops.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why didn't you select `47Z` in `d` in your desired output? It appeared only twice exactly like `FZT` which you did select.

Comment: `data.frame` cannot have duplicated rownames.  So, is it a matrix?

Comment: Sorry, I am not really good in explaining and there was a mistake in the example. Hope it's easier to understand now.
The algorithm works as follows: I look at the first column, choose the first two elements, go to the second, choose the first two elements again, when I reach the third column (c) TS2 is ranked on 1 again, but has been chosen twice before, so I skip it and choose the following two elements. In column d, the first one was chosen once, so I choose it again, the second one (K5S) wasn't chosen before. Finally in e, the first two elements were chosen twice, so they are skipped.

Comment: IMHO for-loops is the solution to go...(loops are not necessarily slow)

Comment: @akrun: sorry, I submitted my edit too soon, row names are changed now, it's a data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using a for-loop :

```
getTopRanking <- function(df,topN=2,maxRep=2){

  uniqueVals <- unique(na.omit(unlist(df)))
  repetitions <- data.frame(count=rep.int(0,length(uniqueVals)),row.names=uniqueVals)

  res <- vector(mode='list',length=ncol(df))
  for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
    colvals <- df[,i]
    topNVals <- head(colvals[colvals %in% 
                             row.names(repetitions)[repetitions$count < maxRep]],topN)
    # pad with NAs (in case we can't find topN elements)
    topNVals <- c(topNVals, rep.int(NA,max(topN-length(topNVals),0)))
    res[[i]] <- topNVals
    repetitions[na.omit(topNVals),1] <- repetitions[na.omit(topNVals),1] + 1
  }
  result <- do.call(cbind.data.frame,res)
  colnames(result) <- colnames(df)
  return(result)
}
```

Usage example :

```
# your example data.frame
df <- 
  data.frame(
    a = c("47Z", "TS2", "3SU", "FZT", "A2D"), 
    b = c("TS2", "47Z", "A2D", "3SU", "K5S"), 
    c = c("TS2", "3SU", "A2D", "FZT",  NA), 
    d = c("3SU", "K5S", "47Z", "FZT", "TS2"),
    e = c("3SU", "47Z", "A2D", "RF9",  NA),
    stringsAsFactors=F)

res <- getTopRanking(df,topN=2,maxRep=2)
> res
    a   b   c   d   e
1 47Z TS2 3SU 3SU A2D
2 TS2 47Z A2D K5S RF9
```

Comment: @Afoy: you're welcome. I think it should be fast enough even with your real data size...